# Deprecated application:openURL method - iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c

The [application:openURL:sourceApplication:annotation:](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate/1623073-application?language=objc) instance method was deprecated in iOS 10. I am having trouble understanding how to convert older methods into the new methods with application:openURL:options:

For example, in this XCT test. How would I update it using the new application:openURL:options call?

```
NSObject *someAnnotation = [NSObject new];

XCTAssertNoThrow([self.appDelegate application:self.application
                                     openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@""]
                           sourceApplication:@"tests"
                                  annotation:someAnnotation],
                 @"Should should not throw an exception");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The newer delegate method has `options` which is a dictionary that replaces the `sourceApplication` and `annotation` parameters as well as possibly containing other keys/values.

See the documentation for `UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey`.

Your code would become something like:

```
NSObject *someAnnotation = [NSObject new];
NSDictionary *options = @{
    UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsSourceApplicationKey: @"tests",
    UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsAnnotationKey: someAnnotation
};

XCTAssertNoThrow([self.appDelegate application:self.application
                                 openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@""]
                                 options:options],
             @"Should should not throw an exception");
```